# The punctuation of “those who” in German

Tags: comma, relative-clause

In relative clauses with *jene*, the relative part is separated with commas, but the following structure confuses me. Shouldn’t it be separated with a comma?

> Die reichsten und gewagtesten Theorien, jene die von größter Komplexität sind, sind in ihr Gegenteil verfallen.

Comment: Where would you place a comma?

Comment: @Alex.S, [...]Theorien, jene, die von[...] something like :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*jene die von größter Komplexität sind*

ist eine Apposition und daher mit Kommata abzutrennen. Natürlich muss der Relativsatz in der Apposition **ebenfalls** mit einem Komma eingeleitet werden:

> Die reichsten und gewagtesten Theorien, jene, die von größter
>   Komplexität sind, sind in ihr Gegenteil verfallen.

Comment: As far as know apposition includes no verbs in it, or am I wrong?

Comment: As it happens in this circumstance, you can leave out the verb (as well as "die" and "von" which makes it somewhat harder to understand (even though it's already rather complex :-):

> jene größter Komplexität